# PHP class not found

Tags: php, class, content-management-system, module

I solved this question my own. The filename was wrong lolz.

Hello everyone!

I'm building a CMS like Drupal and Joomla. I'm working on the module feature (plugins), and I got the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'settings' not found in C:\wamp\www\SYSTEM\view.php on line 22
```

Here is my code:

start.php

```
<?php
//First of all, start with some advertisement
header("X-Powered-By:ZOMFG CMS, and ofcourse PHP, but that's less important");
//Then less impotant stuff lololol.
session_start();                                //Start a session
mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);    //Connect to database
mysql_select_db($db_name);                      //Select a database

//Load core
require_once("core.php");

//Load modules
$res_modules = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$_SERVER["db_prefix"]."modules WHERE enabled=1");
echo mysql_error();
$module_exists = array();
while($row_modules = mysql_fetch_array($res_modules))
{
    //Load module
    $name = $row_modules["name"];
    modules::load_module($name);
    //and initialize it
    eval($name."::init();");
    //Yes, it exists
    $module_exists[$name] = true;
}

//Check if the user wants shit from a module
if(isset($_GET["m"]))//Yes the user want it
{
    //Does the module exist and activated, and has it a function called view?
    if(isset($module_exists[$_GET["m"]]) && method_exists($_GET["m"], "view"))//Yep
    {
        //Load view (should be an array)
        eval("\$module_view = ".$_GET["m"]."::view();");
        if(!is_array($module_view))//Not an array :(
        {
            error::e500module($_GET["m"], $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
        }
        else//The error would kill the entire script, m'kay
        {
            view::index();
        }
    }
    else//Nope, so display error
    {
        error::e404($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    }
}
```

settings.php

```
<?php
class settings
{
    function get($what)
    {
        $result_get = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM ".$_SERVER["db_prefix"]."settings WHERE key='$what'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($result_get) > 0)
        {
            $row_get = mysql_fetch_array($result_get);
            return $result_get["value"];
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

core.php

```
<?php
//Load core classes
require_once("settings.php");
require_once("error.php");
require_once("theme.php");
require_once("view.php");
require_once("modules.php");
```

view.php

```
<?php
class view
{
    function head()
    {
        include("../THEMES/".settings::get("theme")."/head.php");
    }
    function foot()
    {
        include("../THEMES/".settings::get("theme")."/foot.php");
    }
    function left()
    {
        include("../THEMES/".settings::get("theme")."/left.php");
    }
    function right()
    {
        include("../THEMES/".settings::get("theme")."/right.php");
    }
    function index()
    {
        include("../THEMES/".settings::get("theme")."/index.php");
    }
}
```

Start.php is obviously executed first. Not other pages are executed before it, except customsettings.php that contains database information. If I used $_SERVER["db_prefix"] in my code above, it's because I needed a superglobal which is set in customsettings.php:

customsettings.php

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";         //Database host
$db_user = "root";              //Database user
$db_pass = "you may not know this";         //Database password
$db_name = "zomfg";             //Database name
$_SERVER["db_prefix"] = "zomfg_";//Prefix, needs to be superglobal
```

Can anybody help me? It seems that view.php's index function is called before settings.php is included. Sorry if this question is huge, I just want to be clear. Also don't say eval() is evil, I know.

So I want to know why the settings class could not be found. If you need more source code, please comment to this question.

Comment: Stupid as it is, I also had a naming issue. Forgot the .php.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Though you would expect settings.php to be available to view.php because it was included in a script that includes them both, I have found that this usually isn't the case.  You have a couple of choices:

- [`require_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) all the files each class needs in each class file
- write an [`__autoload()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) function so that PHP can find all your classes whenever it thinks it needs one

The 2nd option is more flexible.

If you want to know classes are available from a particular place try outputting [`get_declared_classes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-classes.php)

Comment: Sorry, even including settings.php into view.php does not work :S

Comment: I know what I did wrong. My filename is wrong. Lolz

Comment: +1 for print_r(get_declared_classes()) suggestion

Answer (score 10):

The following does not appy in OP's case but might help others.

Check whether your code uses short tags `<?` instead of `<?php` and if yes, then check your php.ini for `short_open_tag` setting.

By default it is off but if you inherit your php installation from someone else...

Comment: This can happen very easily if moving to a new server where the php.ini file likely has different settings -- great catch @Konstantin.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case somebody stumbles onto this question, I had this problem too and I solved it by making sure that the name of the php file was the same as the name of the php class inside the actual file.

Silly, I know.

Comment: The name of the file doesn't necessarily matter. That might depend on your autoloader.

Comment: hmm weird. Thanks for letting me know. I'm positive that this fixed the problem for me, in any case. 

I was using Eclipse with whatever the default settings are.

Answer (score 0):

There is another problem that may occur and it is worth for anyone to know it. If you use __autoload() and in the file that holds the class being autoloaded you write your PHP tags incorrectly, it will return a class not found error:

File App.php

```
<?

class App extends something
{
    function __construct()
    {

    }
}
?>
```

file index.php

```
<?php

function __autoload($classname) {

    $filename = "./classes/". $classname .".php";
    print("Loading $filename<br>\n");
    include_once($filename);

}


$app = new App();

?>
```

The above code does not work. For it to work you need to replace the short opening PHP tag App.php with a long one:

```
<?php

class App extends something
{
    function __construct()
    {

    }
}
?>
```

There are many comments that could be made about short tags, the version of PHP used, the php.ini file and the rest of it. But it is irrelevant. Just use the long version of the PHP tag

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Sometimes it's problem with path.

Instead of:

```
require_once('foo.php');
```

Try:

```
define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once(__ROOT__ . '/your-dir-name/foo.php');
```