# Fatal error: Class 'Requests_Cookie'

Tags: php

Problem in running site http://bfestaging.netai.net/. When I run the site, it shows:

> Fatal error: Class 'Requests_Cookie' not found in /home/a5583458/public_html/wp-includes/Requests/Cookie/Jar.php on line 171.

```
$cookies = Requests_Cookie::parse_from_headers($return->headers, $url);
```

Comment: I will translate it: `Class 'Requests_Cookie' it's not found`

Comment: It means the class doesn't exist. Not so sure what you're finding hard about the detailed error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP class not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179638/php-class-not-found)